# php mailer is working in local host but not in web server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer. It is working fine in localhost after I changed the "lesssecureapps" option in Gmail. But after hoisting it iss not working in webserver. My code is below:

```
public function sendMail($userEmail, $uniqueKey)
{


        require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';          // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx'; // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('contact@lookwoow.com', 'lookswoow');
        //$mail->addReplyTo('arn617mv@gmail.com', 'sajeev');

        $mail->addAddress("$userEmail");   // Add a recipient

        //$mail->addCC("vishnu@f12technologies.com");
        //$mail->addBCC('vishnu@f12technologies.com');

        $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML


        $mail->Subject = 'Email from LOOKSWOOW';
        $mail->Body    = $uniqueKey;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }


}
```

Comment: You should compare both `php.ini` to find the difference that causes this.  You could also use `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Make sure your hosting plan allows PHP scripts to send emails.

Comment: while posting a question please remove your personal email and password.You can post it as $mail->Username = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';          // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx'; // SMTP password

Comment: [Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: thank you all . its working fine